# Joining multiple column from different file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have 4 tsv (tab separated) files that look like this:

file_1:

```
abc 1
def 2
ghi 3
```

file_2:

```
abc 2
ghi 3
```

file_3:

```
def 1
ghi 2
jkl 4
```

file_4:

```
ghi 3
jkl 4
```

I want to join those file to get 1 tsv file like this:

```
dataset file_1 file_2 file_3 file_4
abc     1      2             
def     2      4            
ghi     3      3      2      3
jkl                   4      4
```

I have try using `awk`

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} 
    FNR==1{f = f "\t" FILENAME} 
    NR==FNR{a[$1] = $2} 
    NR!=FNR{a[$1] = a[$1] "\t" $2} 
    END{printf "dataset%s\n", f; for(i in a) print i, a[i]}
  ' file_{1..4}
```

This command is work, but I got shifted value. Let say, if first and second column have empty value and third and fourth column have value 4 and 4, the output that I got from that command is for first and second column have value 4, but for third and fourth column have empty value.
So I try to join my tsv file separately using `awk` that I mentioned. First only for `file_1` and `file_2` to get `output_1`, then join `file_3` and `file_4` to get `output_2`. After that I use `$ join output_1 output_2` to merge output_1 and output_2 but I only get value that exist in 4 file. I lost data that only exist in one file.

I'll very appreciate if you can give me an advice.

Thank you

Comment: Can you estimate the total size of the 4 files? Easy if they will all fit in memory arrays -- say 400MB.

Comment: Those file contain 2000-3000 rows and the total size for 4 files is only 70kb

Comment: How do you get at value `4` for `def` in `file_2`?  I'd rather see `1` for `file_3`.

Comment: That's my problem. `file_2` should be have empty value but instead have value 4 because the output value is shifted.

Comment: When you say “I want ... to get a TSV file like this:” you should show *the output **that you want**.*

Comment: do you insist in doing it in `awk` ? There are some better tools for this, like python's pandas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ datasets[$1]; fnames[FILENAME]; vals[$1,FILENAME] = $2 }
END {
    printf "%s", "dataset"
    for (fname in fnames) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, fname
    }
    print ""
    for (dataset in datasets) {
        printf "%s", dataset
        for (fname in fnames) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, vals[dataset,fname]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ tail -n +1 file?
==> file1 <==
a       1
b       2
c       3

==> file2 <==
a       2
c       3

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
dataset file1   file2
a       1       2
b       2
c       3       3
```

Add as many files to the list as you like.

Comment: It works well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

With `join (GNU coreutils) 8.30` and "process substitution", you may try

```
join -a1 -a2 -t"    " -oauto  -e " " <(join -a1 -a2 -t" " -oauto  -e "" file[12]) <(join -a1 -a2 -t"    " -oauto  -e " " file[34])
abc 1   2        
def 2       1    
ghi 3   3   2   3
jkl         4   4
```

The `-t` options have a `<TAB>` character value.

Comment: Thank you @RudiC

Comment: It's worth mentioning the files would have to be sorted for `join` to work.

Comment: (1) This answer is hard-coded for four input files.  It could be improved by describing how to adapt it to some other number of files.  (2) This seems to work fine if you leave out the `-e` options.  (3) Note that, if you are using a shell that has command completion, it may be difficult to type a tab on the command line.  It may be possible to enter a tab by typing Ctrl+V first; if you’re using bash, you can use `$'\t'`.  (Scripts do not have this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Advice for now: code for later if you need it.

I would keep three arrays as you read all the files.

(a) For each new file, a hash list of filenames.
(b) For each new dataset, a hash list of $1.
(c) For each row, a hash list of values

```
FNR == 1 { ++htFile[FILENAME]; }
! ($1 in htSet) { ++htSet[$1]; }
{ htVal [FILENAME, $1] = $2; }
```

In an End function, iterate over htFile and htSet.

```
function Table (r, c, buf) {
    buf = "dataset";
    for (c in htFile)
        buf = sprint ("%s\t%s", buf, htFile[c]);
    print buf;
    for (r in htSet) {
        buf = "";
        for (c in htFile)
            buf = sprint ("%s\t%s", buf, htVal[c, r]);
        print substr (buf, 2);
    }
}
END { Table( ); }
```

This does not maintain order of files and datasets in the output table. If that matters, you can keep a sequenced version of the tables and iterate in the original order.

Comment: Thank you @Paul_Pedant

Comment: Wordier than @edmorton , and incomplete. I had to go fetch medication.